# docker-compose image don't run rpoperly, but it does using a dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've got the following docker-compose

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  php-apache:
    image: php:7.3-apache
    command:
      - --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
      - docker-php-ext-install
      - mysqli pdo
      - pdo_mysql
    container_name: php-apache-container
    depends_on:
      - mysql
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./api/:/var/www/html/
    ports:
      - 8010:80
    links:
      - mysql
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: mysql-container
    restart: always
    environment:
      TZ: "America/New_York"
      MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "no"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root_password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db_name
      MYSQL_USER: db_user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: db_password
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
  mysql-data:
```

The php-apache-container keeps restarting.
But if I change this:

```
php-apache:
        image: php:7.3-apache
        command:
          - --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
          - docker-php-ext-install
          - mysqli pdo
          - pdo_mysql
```

into this:

```
php-apache:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: dockerfile
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
```

And the dockerfile have the following content:

```
FROM php:7.3-apache
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql
```

It works, but I don't want to use a dockerfile, how can I make it work without using the dockerfile?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: That `command:` doesn't look like a shell command that could launch the main container process.  Why would you avoid a Dockerfile here, especially to do package installations that shouldn't need to be repeated?

Comment: just trying to have one unique file, the docker-composer file, that's why, I wanted to avoid the dockerfile

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I treated the command as a list but instead I added new lines with command and it works, looks like this:

```
php-apache:
    image: php:7.3-apache
    command: docker-php-ext-install
    command: mysqli pdo
    command: pdo_mysql
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    container_name: php-apache-container
```

Comment: (Are you sure the first three `command:`s aren't just ignored?  A container runs only one command, then exits.)

Comment: That's what I thought, in the documentation it does not say anything about it, but it works, did you try it?